# Is $\Delta$ dense in $\bf Cat$?

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to prove that the functor $i\colon\Delta\to{\bf Cat}$ which regards $[n]\in\Delta$ as a category is [dense](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+functor), to deduce that the nerve $N\colon\bf Cat\to sSet$ is fully faithful: how can I do?

Comment: This may be useful, especially Proposition 6 about halfway down the page: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve

Comment: Your question is *equivalent* to the fully-faithfulness of the nerve functor. And this is well-known and covered in many texts on (higher) category theory. But actually I regard this as one of the best exercises for getting started with higher category theory. After all you just have to unwind the definition of a simplicial map $N(C) \to N(D)$, you will see that this precisely comes down to the definition of a functor.

Comment: Honestly I don't get your point. I'm able to notice that if $Fun([n],C)\cong Fun[n],D)$ for all $n$, then I can induce a bijection on objects fix n=0) and between morphisms (fix n=1), and compatibility with faces and degeneracies implies that these are equivalences (isomorphisms?) between the categories $C,D$. But this is quite redundant: who needs $Fun([n],C)\cong Fun([]n,D)$ for $n\ge 3$? To understand where this redundancy comes from, I wanted to use that precise characterization for fully faithfulness of $N(-)$.

Comment: Although this is a slightly different question, I asked precisely how to manipulate ${\rm colim}\big((i/\mathbf C)\to \Delta\to\bf Cat\big)$ in order to show that it is isomorphic to $\bf C$. The implication $2\iff 3$ follows from the fact that a right adjoint is f.f. iff its counit is iso. Hence I'm left with point 1.

Comment: I agree with Martin: it's easiest to show directly that $N$ is fully faithful. Also, any full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ containing a dense full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ is also a dense subcategory, so if you want you can just show that $\{ [0], [1], [2] \}$ s dense.

Comment: The redundancy in the nerve you allude to is nothing more than the fact that the nerve of a category is 2-coskeletal, which implies that its morphisms are determined by what happens in degrees $\le 2$.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: You won't be able to simplify this colimit directly. But when you unwind the universal property of the colimit, you will end up with the fully-faithfulness of the nerve functor.